# Issue with componentWillReceiveProps in React

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error if I use below code.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.uploadImage.message === 'File uploaded') {
            this.setState({ photostatus: 'image' });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ photostatus: 'input' });
        }
    }
```

But I am not getting error if I use below code

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.uploadImage) {
            this.setState({ photostatus: 'image' });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ photostatus: 'input' });
        }
    }
```

My error is like below

[image]

Comment: Isn't the 2nd snippet with validation better anyways? There could be other props update that doesn't include the `uploadImage` property, hence, the error you're getting.

Comment: The second snippet should be used unless you want to check for the specific message 'File uploaded'.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are trying to find the value of the `message` property of an `undefined`.

You have to change your if condition something like this,

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.uploadImage && (nextProps.uploadImage.message === 'File uploaded')) {
        this.setState({ photostatus: 'image' });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ photostatus: 'input' });
    }
}
```